# pd.to_numeric could not convert string to float

Tags: python, pandas, user-interface

```
def openfiles():
    file1 = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Text Files",".csv"),("All files","*")))
    read_text=pd.read_csv(file1)
    displayed_file.insert(tk.END,read_text)
    read_text['OPCODE'] = pd.to_numeric(read_text['OPCODE'],errors = 'coerce').fillna(0.0)
    read_text['ADDRESS'] = pd.to_numeric(read_text['ADDRESS'],errors = 'coerce').fillna(0.0)
    classtype1=np.argmax(model.predict(read_text), axis=-1)
    tab2_display_text.insert(tk.END,read_text)
```

When running this code it shows "could not convert string to float".

Link of the csv file that is used to as datafram: https://github.com/Yasir1515/Learning/blob/main/Book2%20-%20Copy.csv

Complete code link (probmatic code is at line 118-119): https://github.com/Yasir1515/Learning/blob/main/PythonApplication1.py

Comment: Can you please post the full error traceback?

Comment: See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) for reasons **not** to do it.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with `tkinter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your data `ADDRESS` is a hexadecimal number and `OPCODE` is a list of hexadecimal numbers. I don't know why would you want to convert hex numbers to float. You should convert them to integers.

The method `to_numeric` is not suitable to convert hex string to integer, or handle a list of hex numbers. You need to write help function:

```
def hex2int(x):
  try:
    return int(x, 16)
  except:
    return 0

def hex_list2int_list(zz):
  return [hex2int(el) for el in zz.split()]
```

Now replace relevant lines:

```
read_text['OPCODE'] = read_text['OPCODE'].apply(hex_list2int_list)
read_text['ADDRESS'] = read_text['ADDRESS'].apply(hex2int)
```

Comment: why you apply hex_list2int_list? Is this needed to apply both columns i.e  read_text['OPCODE'] and read_text['ADDRESS']?

Comment: The data in `OPCODE` column is a list of hex numbers. Your code implies it should be converted. To convert a list of strings you have to convert each one separately. This is what `hex_list2int_list` does. The data in read_text['ADDRESS'] contains only a single number and thus needs only a single `hex2int` conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I look at your CSV file. The column OPCODE contains one row with a long string of some numbers separated by space(' '). therefor you cannot cast that type of value to numeric type (the string '88 99 77 66' != numeric type). I can suggest some solution to split those many values in the column OPCODE to many rows and then perform the to_numeric method after afterwards you can make manipulation and return it to the previous form.
what I suggest is:

```
read_text=pd.read_csv(file1)

new_df = pd.concat([pd.Series(row['ADDRESS'], row['OPCODE'].split(' '))              
                    for _, row in a.iterrows()]).reset_index()
                    
new_df['OPCODE'] = pd.to_numeric(new_df['OPCODE'],errors = 'coerce').fillna(0.0)
```